# Test if std::iterator is at start of range without referring to collection

Tags: c++, c++11, std

With simple code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
 
int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v{ 3, 1, 4 };
    auto vi = v.begin();
    if (some_condition_or_other)
        vi++;

    if (vi != v.begin())
        std::cout << *std::prev(vi) << '\n';
}
```

Can the `if (vi != v.begin())` be replaced by an expression using `vi` only? It would be nice if there was something like `if (!vi.at_begin())` (and `at_end()` for symmetry), so is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: No, because an iterator itself has no idea of it's index inside a container.

Comment: @acraig5075 I thought that was the answer, but I wanted to ask the question anyway. The code I inherited crashed on an unguarded `std::prev(vi)` and `vi` was initialised a few pages earlier so the collection wasn't immediately obvious.